# In TypeScript, what's the difference between the `lib.es6.d.ts` and `lib.es2015.d.ts`?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

From my understanding, the ES6 and the ES2015 is the same thing. But in typescript, there are 2 type declaration for these 2 things: `lib.es6.d.ts` and `lib.es2015.d.ts`. What's difference? Which one should I use?

Comment: How do their contents differ?

Comment: Their contents are different very much. The es6.d.ts is more than 20k lines, but the es2015.d.ts include some files like es2015.core, es2015.promise, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES6 and ES2015 are synonymous. Both TypeScript `target`s and `lib`s of same names are expected to behave similarly in TypeScript - and they are.

`lib.d.ts` and `lib.es6.d.ts` are cumulative library files. They are [generated from other libraries](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/v2.8.0/src/lib):

> The files within this directory are used to generate lib.d.ts and lib.es6.d.ts.

They include respective spec libraries plus `DOM`.

The difference between `lib.es6.d.ts` and `lib.es2015.d.ts` is that the former is included by default with `target` set to `ES6` when no `lib` is specified, while the latter is used with `lib` set to `ES6`. I.e. `--target ES6` is the same as `--target ES6 --lib ES6,DOM,DOM.Iterable,Scripthost`.

`ES2015` library is fine-grained, so `ES6` or `ES2015` can be replaced with [a subset of features](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#including-built-in-type-declarations-with---lib) when necessary: `ES2015.Core`, etc.