# Cannot find name Symbol

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, tsc

For the below code:

```
const MY_KEY: symbol = Symbol();
let obj: object = {};

obj[MY_KEY] = 123;
console.log(obj[MY_KEY]);   // 123
```

For the below configuration `tscconfig.json`:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": ["es2015"]
    },

  }
```

---

Files

```
$ ls
  tsconfig.json  tstut.html  tstut.js  tstut.ts
```

---

How to resolve below error?

```
$ tsc --version
     Version 2.8.3
$ tsc tstut.ts
     tstut.ts(1,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Symbol'.
```

---

Comment: In Node, `lib` should be  `["es2015"]` (and likely higher, too). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49290623/3731501

Comment: @estus With `"lib": ["es2015"]` I see same error with `tsc tstut.ts`.

Comment: Consider providing a way to replicate the problem - a repo or something. I'd say that config just isn't applied for some reason. It's tsconfig.json and not tsc`c`onfig.json, for starters.

Comment: @estus [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Front-end-programming/tree/master/TypeScript) is my repo. Read [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/25401). Applied `npm install @types/node -g`

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/25401 is a band aid, it should be es2015 because you're using other ES6 features, too. I cannot replicate the problem. I run `tsc` without any arguments, and it only shows problems in source files that aren't related to Symbol. TS 2.8.3 here.

Comment: @estus Removed local `node_modules` folder, which was created yesterday before using `Symbol`. Query edited. [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Front-end-programming/tree/master/TypeScript) is the repo

Comment: As I mentioned, it should be **tsc without any arguments**. `tsc` with arguments ignores existing tsconfig.json

Comment: @estus Now, `Symbol` is resolved. Got an error on `console`. Thank you

Comment: @estus Is `tsc` app a plugin architecture, picking corresponding `*.ts` for resolving symbols based on inputs in config file `tsconfig.json`? I wrote a plugin [app](https://github.com/shamhub/Systems_programming_C/tree/master/10_C_layers_arch/DESIGN3) sometime back using C.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by inputs, but it automatically picks typings from `node_modules/@types` or custom location, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file (tsconfig.json), specify ECMAScript target version to 'ES2015' or later ('ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'). 'ES6' works for me, too.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2015",
    }
}
```